# How can I post JSON data to an MVC 4 controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, angularjs

I have setup my controllers like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Contact()
{
      ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

      return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact(string json)
{
      return Json(new { received=json });
}
```

The request is being sent using Angular.JS like this:

```
$scope.update = function (message) {
        $http({
            url: '/Contact',
            method: "POST",
            data: message
        }).success(function (data) {
            //$scope.master = angular.copy(message);
            $scope.master = data;
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.master = {message: "failed"}
        });
};
```

But the response I am getting back right now is:

```
{
  "received": null
}
```

So, I believe my problem has something to do with the `string json` argument I defined in the controller. **What is the proper way to receive JSON?**

**Update 1:**

I updated my $http request to look like this:

```
$scope.update = function (message) {
    $http({
        url: '/Contact',
        method: "POST",
        data: {json:message}
    }).success(function (data) {
        //$scope.master = angular.copy(message);
        $scope.master = data;
    }).error(function (data) {
        $scope.master = {message: "failed"}
    });
};
```

But am still getting the same result.

Comment: Why would you want the modelbinder to not bind to a strongly-typed object, and instead provide a raw JSON string?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I don't know that I would. I took this route so that I could send the data in real time with Javascript. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: If you post what your JSON looks like, I'll post an example in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your data like below, otherwise MVC will expect the parameter name should be `id` instead of `json`

```
 data: {json:JSON.stringify(message)}
```

Comment: Still getting: `{ "received": null }` anything else I might be missing?

Comment: @anwyatt, need to use JSON.Stringify. UPdated my answer